# Click on google map marker won't open the info window after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map which will open a dialog box on a double click on the map. If the user click OK, then it will add a marker on the map. This marker will open the info windows on the first click (good behavior).

Another part of the code will display markers with info windows directly when the page load, those markers wont open the info window on the first click (bad behavior). The pointer will change from the hand to a finger on the first click, then on the second click the window will open.

The following display the stores at the loading time:

```
//display the markers
for(var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(stores[i][8], stores[i][9]);
  all_stores_markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({                       
                                     position: pos,
                                     map: map,
                                     title: stores[i][1],
                                     clickable: true
                         }));
   all_stores_markers[i].html = 'some content';
   google.maps.event.addListener(all_stores_markers[i], 'click', function () {
    // where I have added .html to the marker object.
                                            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                                            infowindow.open(map, this);  
                                            console.log("click marker");
                                    });                                  
}
```

This part is when the user is click OK in the dialog box after a double click on the map. The following would make the marker clickable from the first click:

```
all_stores_markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({                       
                                position: location,
                                map: map,
                                clickable: true
                        }));
all_stores_markers[all_stores_markers.length-1].html = 'some content';
                        google.maps.event.addListener(all_stores_markers[all_stores_markers.length-1], 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                                infowindow.open(map, this);  
                        });
```

Here is the content of stores :

```
 array(2) { [0]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(8) "aaaaaaaa" [2]=> string(15) "fjefjdoiajfdhai" [3]=> string(13) "jadoidjasoijd" [4]=> string(4) "7575" [5]=> string(10) "City folle" [6]=> string(9) "Australia" [7]=> string(13) "http://go.com" [8]=> string(8) "-20.0559" [9]=> string(7) "135.967" [10]=> string(10) "1818181818" [11]=> string(10) "1818181818" } [1]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(8) "New Shop" [2]=> string(11) "adjakdjakld" [3]=> string(6) "eqwewq" [4]=> string(4) "4343" [5]=> string(4) "Arff" [6]=> string(9) "Australia" [7]=> string(15) "http://test.com" [8]=> string(8) "-28.9985" [9]=> string(6) "123.75" [10]=> string(8) "92129181" [11]=> string(8) "82828282" } }
```

I can't see much difference between both part of the code. Any idea?

Comment: there is no issue for me with your code(no matter if I set a title or not). Can you post the contents of `stores` ? Which browser/API-version do you use?

Comment: I use firefox, api v3. Variable content added.

Comment: There is(has been) a bug with FF39 and the experimental API-version( https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8278 ). With your code it doesn't happen to me, but when you didn't load a specific API-version force the load of the release-version (`v=3`), otherwise the experimental version will be loaded

Comment: The way i load the api is this <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false&libraries=places"></script> and you are right i am using FF39. Could be that bug.

Comment: so remove the `.exp` from the API-src: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&signed_in=false&libraries=places%22%3E%3C/script%3E

Comment: Working, you are a google map guru :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to ask this question, but I found the solution.

For some very very strange reason, the difference of code was around the "title" attribute of the marker. I removed it and everything is fine now.

I can't explain why this would have an impact on the click...